# Turn off comment/post inbox notifications

Tags: support, feature-request, comments

Is it possible to turn off the notifications from comments or posts?

Looking for this features .

Comment: No.‪‪‪‪‪‪‪‪‪‪‪‪

Comment: Nope. If you own it, and someone comments on it (or @ notifies you, if a comment) then you'll get notified. Can it get annoying if a debate is happening in the comments of your post? Yes. Yes it can.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the prompt reply

Comment: @Kendra yeah, sometimes is quite annoying :P

Comment: Well, you can disassociate it, if you insist. (Don't abuse it though, or SE might decide that the best way to honour your request is to remove your account.)

Comment: @Deduplicator Don't..I love `SE` and `SO` very much

Comment: If you want to turn this into a feature request (right now it's just a straight-up question), you should rephrase what you're saying.  You should say something like, "It should be possible to...", and give supporting reasons why.

Comment: Also, specific implementation details really help feature requests.  For example, do you want to disable all notifications?  Notifications of a specific type?  Notifications from specific sources (this post, that post's comment replies)?  How would it look on the UI?

Comment: If there's annoying excesive comments, they probably shouldn't be there. You could point to commenters to chat.

Comment: @bjb568 Or if it's bad enough, flag for moderator attention.