# Asking for help multiple times in comments

Tags: discussion, behavior, comment-replies

What do you do when a user who posted a question pings you multiple times in comments to ask for help?

Recently, I just wanted to point a little error in the code that might not solve the issue, so instead of answer, I commented.

And the author is like

> @myname, please help!

and

> @myname, help!

I did point out a little problem and tell the author that when they want to get more help, they should please show more Information about what they tried.

But they just told "I tried all my way", and keep saying "help me".

I think the author doesn't understand what I suggested. What should I do? Or should I just let him keep tagging "@your_name help", and ignore it?

Comment: Flag the comment(s) for moderator attention. Someone pinging you repeatedly with "please help" is just being annoying. That is not an appropriate use of comments.

Comment: I often think "Answering your question doesn't mean that I am volunteering to be your buddy for the remainder of your project" but conveying that tactfully can be hard, and seem unhelpful.

Comment: @NickCox I've personally stopped trying to explain it. If somebody tries to ask for help with something unrelated, I just don't answer. I've no real obligation to anyway.

Comment: @VLAZ Indeed, that too. Sometimes if you recognise an identifier as that of someone clingy, it's best to back off, knowing what might ensue. Nevertheless much of Meta, when it's not about the company, is about handling those new to SO who don't get SO at all and how best to use it (which is certainly puzzling to those who think we are a help line). Ignoring them  is not ideal either.

Comment: @NickCox I agree, we *should* be helping newcomers. On the other hand...it's sometimes hard. I'd rather not respond than say something that might be perceived as unwelcoming.

Comment: This raises an interesting Q.  If you delete _all_ your comments,  are you still pinged if they @ you again?

Comment: @chris No, you cannot be the target of a ping if you have no visible interactions with the post. So deleting *all* of your comments will work. But may not be the best thing, if you first comment conveys some useful information/advice. In that case, I’d prefer you flag the annoying comments so a moderator can address the actual problem.

Comment: Hopefully the mod flag results in the user's account being permanently destroyed. They evidently aren't interested in learning, they're just a help vampire that wants their problem solved, and as such they are a net drain on the site.

Answer (score 14):

If I post a comment and someone begins pinging me repeatedly to force my attention, I delete my comment. It's unfortunate, since my comment may have had useful, relevant information. I'm increasingly of the opinion though that life's too short to stress out about things like that, and that my effort is better spent elsewhere helping people that respect my time.

Especially if the OP is being difficult and not elaborating or otherwise not working toward solving the problem, they aren't worth the time. It sounds awful when it's phrased like that, but if you're knowledgeable, there are definitely other people out there that will appreciate the help and be more receptive.

Comment: The implication that some people expect too much invites assent. But in deleting  you deprive others thereby of a comment that might be interesting or useful. Here on SO comments are reckoned trivial any way but elsewhere on SE (my primary affiliation is Cross Validated) comments can even be the best part of a thread.

Comment: SO needs an option to turn off notifications for posts. Facebook has it, theres no excuse for SO not having it.

Comment: @NickCox If I felt at all confident that the question and attached comments would be at all helpful to future users, then yes, that would be a valid concern. In my experience though, many low-effort, help-vampire questions end up just getting deleted anyways, and the comments along with them. If not deleted, they just go stale and should probably be deleted.

Comment: @TheBatman See [this feature request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310162/turn-off-comment-post-inbox-notifications).

Answer (score 3):

You should flag comment and let moderators deal with it.